# How to unit test a simple repository that contains a dagger injection?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking, dagger-2

I'm trying to unit test a simple repository but it gives me a `NullPointerException`. The repository contains one method which depends on a webService. The webService is working fine (I successfully tested). I'm using Retrofit for webService and Dagger for dependency injection. Below is my code:

**webService**:

```
public interface UserWebService {
    @GET(USER_ENDPOINT)
    Call<UserResponse> getUser();
}
```

**Repository**:

```
public class UserRepository {
    @Inject
    UserWebService mUserWebService;

    public void getUserEmail() throws IOException {       
      mUserWebService.getUser().execute().body().getUser().getEmail();
    }
}
```

**Unit Test**:

```
public class UserRepositoryTest {
    @Mock
    private UserWebService mUserWebService;

    @Test
    public void getUserEmail() throws IOException {
        when(mUserWebService.getUser().execute().body().getUser().getEmail())
                .thenReturn("some@email.com");

    }
}
```

P.S. The `NullPointerException` is thrown because of `mUserWebService` which is understandable but how can I test this unit anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Unit test usually means you test a single component, supplying friendlies / mocks / stubs to test some behavior. There is no need for Dagger in unit tests, so to answer your question you should simply pass your mock to `UserRepository`.

```
UserRepository repository = new UserRepository();
repository.mUserWebService = mUserWebService;
```

---

You could / should consider switching to constructor injection though, since there is no need to field-inject your repository manually. Then your test also becomes much cleaner.

```
public class UserRepository {

  UserWebService mUserWebService;

  @Inject
  public UserRepository(UserWebService userWebService) {
    mUserWebService = userWebService;
  }
}

// and then simply call the constructor...

UserRepository repository = new UserRepository(mUserWebService);
```